# Заменить постояный вызов assert

Tags: c++, qt5, c++11

```
class Base {
public:
    int err;
    Base() {
        err = func1();
        assert(err);
        err = func2(arg1);
        assert(err);
        err = func3(arg2, arg3);
        assert(err);
        // some code
    }
}
```

Можно как нибудь красивее написать?

у меня есть такое решение:

```
class Base {
public:
    int err;
    Base() {
        if (err = func1()
         || err = func2(arg1)
         || err = func3(arg2, arg3) {
            assert(err);
        }
        // some code
    }
}
```

Это правильное решение? может что то можно сделать красивее?

Comment: А что вам тут не нравится?

Comment: дублирование строки assert

Comment: Не вижу тут ничего плохого. Но вы можете ее вызов поместить в сами функции `func`

Comment: Здесь нет никакого дублирования, `assert` проверяет три разных кода ошибки.

Comment: Советую написать свой `#define my_assert(expr) do { auto res = expr; assert(res); } while(false)`, и использовать `my_assert(func1()); my_assert(func2(arg1));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Теоретически**, Вы хотели бы писать:

```
    assert(func1());
    assert(func2(arg1));
    assert(func3(arg2, arg3));
```

Но тогда при компиляции в Release режиме макрос раскроется в "ничего" и не будет даже вызова функций. Это решается написанием своего собственного макроса, который безусловно вычисляет аргумент и затем вызывает оригинальный `assert`:

```
#define my_assert(...) do { decltype(auto) res = __VA_ARGS__; assert(res); } while(false)
```

и использовать как

```
    my_assert(func1());
    my_assert(func2(arg1));
    my_assert(func3(arg2, arg3));
```

---

Зачем нужен `do { ... } while(false)`? Это стандартная техника в макросах, которая вынуждает пользователя писать `;` после вызова. Если бы реализация была `#define my_assert(...) { decltype(auto) res = __VA_ARGS__; assert(res); }`, то строка `my_assert(f())` была бы валидной (без `;` на конце!). Так что это лишь вопрос консистентности кода.

Без макроса обойтись нельзя. Оригинальный `assert` является макросом, так как он вынужден работать с `__LINE__`, `__FILE__`, `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` и прочими макро-определениями, чтобы выводить подробное сообщение об ошибке. Поэтому и обертка над ним обязана быть макросом (по крайней мере до появления [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/source_location))

---

Если важно сохранять результат, можно модифицировать макрос соответствующим образом, чтобы не создавалась временная переменная.

Comment: `#define my_assert(...)    err = __VA_ARGS__; assert(!err)` - а так чем плохо? после такого макроса тоже нужно писать `;`?

Comment: @KtoTo так тоже можно, но сработает только если у Вас `err` всегда с таким именем, в случае с созданием новой переменной нужен новый скоуп (`{ .. }`), иначе будет дублирование имён

Comment: и еще вопрос, а так будет ошибка: `#define my_assert(x) err = x; assert(!err)`?

Comment: `err` является полем класса

Comment: @KtoTo ошибка будет в случае `my_assert(f<int, int>())`, например. Запятая станет разделителем аргументов, а т.к. макрос принимает один аргумент, то и код не скомпилируется.

Comment: а еще вопрос, можно сделать так: `#define my_assert(err, ...) err = __VA_ARGS__; assert(!err)` и передавать переменную куда записывать ошибку `my_assert(err, func());`?

Comment: @KtoTo можно :)

Answer (score 0):

Ваше решение:

```
if (err = func1()
  || err = func2(arg1)
  || err = func3(arg2, arg3) {
    assert(err);
}
```

неверно, потому что по идее `err` должно быть комбинацией возвращаемых значений функций, а вы его каждый раз переприсваиваете.

Вопрос можно ли сделать лучше, чем оригинальное:

```
err = func1();
assert(err);
err = func2(arg1);
assert(err);
err = func3(arg2, arg3);
assert(err);
```

На первый взгляд, можно написать изящнее, например, так:

```
int err = func1() && func2(arg1) && func3(arg2, arg3);
assert(err);
```

но к сожалению, это будет не всегда правильным. Дело в том, что логические выражения вычисляются частично, конкретно данное выражение будет вычисляться только до первого возвращенного нуля. Если хоть один член логического AND является ложью, всё выражение также будет ложным, и вычислять остальные члены нет необходимости. В некоторых языках есть возможность задать полное вычисление, но C++ такой языковой конструкции не предоставляет.

Подобную сокращенную конструкцию всё же можно использовать, если после возврата нуля дальнейшая работа теряет смысл и, соответственно, вызывать оставшиеся функции нет необходимости. Но в общем случае ваш оригинальный код (с `assert` после каждого вызова) сократить нельзя, потому что он работает всегда, и всегда вызывает функции в заданном порядке (что временами бывает важным). Разве что с использованием хитрых макросов, как в другом ответе, но в таком случае "упрощение" получается сильно сложнее оригинального кода.